# FadeIn after ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with an animation (fadeIn). It doesn't work after ajax. There is just NO ANIMATION but the content appears.

My code is like:

```
function ajax(varia) {

    return $.ajax({

        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?fn=' + varia,
        data: { token: "mytoken" }

    });

}
```

Function with ajax works fine...

```
ajax("login").done(function (data) {

    $("body").prepend(data);

}).done(function () {

    // The #login have atribute style="display: none;"
    $("#login").fadeIn(500); 

});
```

This problem can be resolved with using delay before the fade, but i think it should be fine without this. Why it's not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats probably because JavaScript is an asynchroneus language. What you are experiening is a synchronization issue:

Your ajax is done, you are firing DOM manipulation (`prepend()`), and imidiately after you fire it you do the `fadeIn()` but the fadeIn is complete before your data is prepended, so probably you'are calling `fadeIn()` on an element that doesn't exist yet.

Try this:

```
ajax("login").done(function (data) {  
    $("body").prepend(data);       
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#login").fadeIn(500);        
    },0);
});
```

And read this to understand why using timeout 0 is sometimes helpful: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

By wrapping your action with `setTimeout` function you are basically telling: "wait until everything is done before doing this".

Here's the fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL6Lhs8z/)

Comment: Sorry, made a small mistake, fixed it. Should be working now as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put both calls into the same .done()-Block?

I think this should work:

```
ajax("login", "html").done(function (data) {

    $("body").prepend(data);

    // The #login have atribute style="display: none;"
    $("#login").fadeIn(500); 

});
```

In this case it should be guaranteed that the two lines of code are executed 
successively.

I've made an live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xLo93d29/
For me it works.

Comment: I added a working example. Maybe you can compare it with your implementation. Then let me know if it works ;).

Answer (score 0):

You should use "success" instead of "done":

```
function ajax(varia) {

  $.ajax({

    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?fn=' + varia,
    data: { token: "mytoken" },
    success: function(data) {
      $("body").prepend(data);
      // The #login have atribute style="display: none;"
      $("#login").fadeIn(500); 
    }

   });

}
ajax("login", "html");
```

Comment: Ajax returns a $.Deferred object, which has no method `success`, has `done()` instead. Success is a callback function inside ajax, but since he's returning it as an object he should be using `.done()`. Look here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Comment: @bwitkowicz you're absolutely right. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've updated the answer to eliminate the mistake.

Comment: Good, than I'm removing my downvote from your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this

```
.done(function (data) {
    var $data = $(data).hide();
    $data.prependTo($("body"));
    $data.fadeIn(500);
});
```